# Linear independence of vectors over the finite and real fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose there exist a set of $n$-dimensional linearly independent vectors $v_1,\dots,v_m$ over a finite field $GF(p)$.
If we interpret the coordinates of $v_1,\dots,v_m$ as scalars in $\mathbb{R}$, can we say anything about the independence of these vectors over the real field?

For example, if [1 0 0], [0 1 0] and [0 0 1] are vectors defined over GF(2) and then we interpreted their coordinates as real scalars, then these vectors are also independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

I've done some more numerical checks over higher order fields and higher dimensional vectors and they seem to be independent over $\mathbb{R}$ but I couldn't show it rigorously. How can I prove or disprove this statement?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If these are vectors over a finite field, then how can you multiply them by real numbers? Do you mean to interpret them as coordinate vectors, and then identify $\Bbb F_p$ with the set of reals $\{0,\cdots,p-1\}$ in order to turn the vectors into coordinate vectors with real scalars? (Which seems like a mathematically unnatural operation to do.)

Comment: Yes I interpret them as vectors with real scalars.
I take the vectors that are originally defined over a finite field, for example [1 0 0 ], [0 1 0 ] and [0 0 1] that are defined over GF(2), and then do the operations over the real field to check for independence. Obviously this example has independent vectors over $\mathbb{R}$ but I want to see if I  can generally prove it.

Comment: You should know you have to **say that**, because $\Bbb F_p$ is not automatically a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Assume without loss of generality that the vectors $v_i$ are simply elements of $\Bbb F_p^n$.  The vectors $v_1,\dots,v_m$ can be made the columns of a matrix.  The $n \times m$ matrix $M$ of entries in $\Bbb F_p$ is invertible if and only if some $n \times n$ minor (determinant of a submatrix) is non-zero.

So, if the vectors are linearly independent, $M$ will have an $m \times m$ submatrix whose determinant is non-zero.  Thus, if the entries are taken as elements of $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb R$, the determinant is not a multiple of $p$.   Thus, if the entries are taken as elements of $\Bbb R$ (as you said), the submatrix will have a non-zero determinant, which means that the columns of the full matrix are linearly independent.

Comment: when you said " $\dots$ some $n \times n$ minor (determinant of a submatrix) $\dots$ " you meant $m \times m$ right?

Comment: Yes!!${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

If some vectors with integer coordinates are linear dependent over $\mathbb{R}$ then there is a non-trivial linear combination with rational (and even integer) coefficients, as you see by considering the usual Gauss elimination (row reductions). From this it follows that your statement is true.